# JPA, removing an entity which has found by different manager

Tags: java, jpa

Assume we have a simple entity bean, like above

```
@Entity
public class Schemes implements serializable{
...
@Id private long id;
...
}
```

I find a record using `find` method and it works perfect, the problem is I cannot manipulate it(remove) by another `EntityManager` later, for example I find it with a method, and later I want to remove it, what is the problem?! if I find it with same manager again I would remove it, but if object has found by another manager I cannot.

```
@ManagedBean @SessionScopped class JSFBean {
private Schemes s;
  public JSFBean(){
    ....
    EntityManager em;//.....
    s=em.find(Schemes.class,0x10L);//okay!
    ....
  }

  public void remove(){//later
    ....
    EntityManager em;//.....
    em.getTransaction().begin();
    em.remove(s);//Error! some weird error, it throws IllegalArgumentException!
    em.getTransaction().commit();
    ....
  }
}
```

many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably getting a `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Removing a detached instance`.

The two EMs do not share a persistence context and for the second EM, your object is considered detached. Trying to remove a detached object will result in an `IllegalArgumentException`.

You can refetch the entity before the removal:

```
Schemes originalS = em.find(Schemes.class, s.getId());
em.remove(originalS);
```

**EDIT** You can also delete the entity without fetching it first by using parametrized bulk queries:

```
DELETE FROM Schemes s WHERE s.id = :id
```

Be aware that bulk queries can cause problems on their own. First, they bypass the persistence context, meaning that whatever you do with a bulk query will not be reflected by the objects in the persistence context. This is less an issue for delete queries than for update queries. Secondly, if you have defined any cascading rules on your entites - they will be ignored by a bulk query.

Comment: many thanks dude, and what if `s` has updated(local)? does `merge()` here to both update and attach it to the current context? I really don't want it get's merged(update) before removing, it will caused many inconsistency at database.

Comment: Why merge() and not just make it managed again through for example find()? You would use merge() if you'd want to update a detached entity.

Comment: @Gimby - excellent point, thanks Gimby. I will update the answer.

Comment: @Gimby so you say there is no any way to just attach a detached entity to current context?! I don't see either `find` it or `merge` it for attaching, it doesn't look optimized(at least for me).

Comment: Assume the record is to much heavy, isn't there any better way?!

Comment: @parsaporahmad - for expensive entities, you can use bulk queries, like `DELETE ...WHERE ...` but they have issues on their own - they bypass the persistence context and do not cascade to related entities.

Comment: Point for mentioning that you can delete through querying too, it isn't exactly necessary to first fetch the entity only to remove it a fraction of a second later.